# how to combine java config and xml to integrate spring security in Spring 3.1?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm trying to integrate Spring security to my app which uses java config.

Following the examples in the book Spring Security 3.1 I managed to get things working with the auto generated login page. But when I try to replace that with a custom page I get

```
No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/myapp/login/form]
```

I have also noticed that while the book's example project's jsps can include urls like

```
"/resources/css/main.css"
```

they don't work in my app, instead I have to prefix them with "../"

The difference is that my app uses java config also for the servlet mapping ("/") while the book's example uses web.xml (also "/")

What could be the reason that my app cannot find /resources but ../resources and also fails to find the login page?

my web.xml

```
<display-name>My Web Application</display-name>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigClass</param-name>
    <param-value>com.myapp.config.AppInitializer</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring/security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

And the AppInitializer class:

```
public class AppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext context) throws ServletException {
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext root = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    root.register(ApplicationContext.class);
    ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = context.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(root));
    dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    dispatcher.addMapping("/");
    }
}
```

The request mapping handlers etc. are defined in the ApplicationContext.class referred by the AppInitializer. They are the same as in the book's example.

Also, the login.jsp is identical to the example project at the moment.

Comment: Can you give examples of your JSPs and configuration? You may need to ensure you are using the <c:url> tag

Comment: Sure thing. Added the configs to the question.

Comment: How is the controller that processes /login/form being added to the configuration (i.e. are you sure it is being loaded)? What is the full URL being requested? How are you creating the URL that the user is being sent to? If that is configured in Spring Security what does it look like? You may be including the context root of your application in the Security Config and need to remove it (context root is automatically added for you)

Comment: Great! Adding the controller for /login/form worked and now my app finds the login page. However, I'm still unable to get to static resources like "/resources/css/main.css". It always ends up with No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/myapp/resources/css/main.css]

Comment: Strange enough, adding <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/> to my mvc-config.xml and removing the java resource mapping fixed the issue. Any ideas why the java config didn't work? It does get read, I have my JPA config there and everything works fine.